# Triângulo de Pascal fica em for infinito

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for

Estou fazendo um código que gera um triângulo de Pascal para um projeto meu, mas quando eu rodo ele fica travado, como se o for fosse infinito.

```js
function pascal(n) {
 var d;
 var uau = "";
 var line;
 var i;
 for(line = 1; line += 1; line <= n){
  d = 1;
  for(i = 1; i += 1; i <= line){
   uau += d.toString();
   d *= (line - i) / i;
  }
  uau += "<br>";
 };
 return uau;
}

$("#uau").click(function(){
 var n = $("#inp").val();
 document.write(pascal(n));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>teste</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <input type="number" id="inp">
  <button type="button" id="uau">UAU</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O principal problema é que está fazendo incremento onde deveria colocar a condição de fim do laço e está colocando a condição onde deveria ter ação a ser executada em cada passo do laço. Invertendo isso resolve o problema. Eu aproveitei e simplifiquei um pouco, mas poderia dar melhores nomes para as variáveis também. Tirei a parte que não estava relacionada ao problema para demonstrar funcionando mais facilmente.

Eu acho que tem outros problemas até de lógica do que está fazendo, a fórmula provavelmente não é essa, mas respondi o que foi perguntado, até porque os outros erros não são de programação.

```js
function pascal(n) {
    var uau = "";
    for (var line = 1, d = 1; line <= n; line++) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= line; i++) {
            uau += d.toString();
            d *= (line - i) / i;
        }
        uau += "<br>";
    };
    return uau;
}
console.log(pascal(10));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/NestedLoop.js).

Comment: Obrigado, me salvou